# Why is only one proton transferred in the reaction between sulfuric acid and sodium chloride

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, acid-base

$$\ce{NaCl + H2SO4 -> NaHSO4 + HCl}$$

The above reaction happens, but why doesn't the following happen? Or does it but only when one of the reactants is in excess?

$$\ce{2NaCl + H2SO4 -> Na2SO4 + 2HCl}$$

The second reaction seems plausible to me. How can I predict whether a similar type of reaction will be like the first equation or the second equation?

Comment: The first reaction takes place when sulfuric acid is concentrated.

Comment: related: http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/5048/hcl-synthesis-from-sulfuric-acid-and-sodium-salt, http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/4750/reactions-of-sodium-halides-with-sulphuric-acid?lq=1

Answer (score 3):

Sodium bisulphate (pKa ~ 2 - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sulfuric_acid) is a much weaker acid that hydrochloric acid (pKa = ~ -7), which means that chloride is not a strong enough base to deprotonate sodium bisulphate.

However all acid pbased reactions are at equilibrium.  Roughly one part in 10^9 of the species involve sulphate anion, which for all practical purposes is negligible.

Table of pKa charts: http://www.lauher.com/che142/acidbase.pdf

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sulfuric_acid says II pKa is ~2

Comment: better data, changing answer.  Although what those pKas mean is a bit questionable.