# Why do reactions of sodium halides with sulfuric acid produce sodium hydrogen sulfate instead of sodium sulfate?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, acid-base, halides

In the reaction of sodium halides with sulfuric acid, sodium hydrogen sulfate is produced \eqref{NaHSO4}. Why would this be produced instead of sodium sulfate \eqref{Na2SO4}?
\begin{align}
\ce{NaX + H2SO4 &-> NaHSO4 + HX}\tag1\label{NaHSO4}\\
\ce{2 NaX + H2SO4 &-> Na2SO4 + 2 HX}\tag2\label{Na2SO4}
\end{align}

Is this because of lower energy requirement for this reaction compared to forming sodium sulfate?

Comment: Related: [Why do sodium halides react so differently with sulfuric acid?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/4750)